# Раскрасить ячейки в строке DataGrid в соответствии с другой строкой - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Добрый вечер. Есть пара нерешенных задач в wpf, над которыми уже 3 дня ломаю голову. Буду благодарен любой помощи. Имеется следующий грид:

```
____________________________________
|заголовок 1|заголовок 2|заголовок 3|
____________________________________
|текст 1    |текст 2    |текст 3   |
____________________________________
|красн.     |желт.      |красн.    |
____________________________________
```

Мне необходимо раскрасить задний фон у строки |текст 1|текст 2|текст 3| в соответствии со значениями в строке |красн. |желт. |красн. | . А строку с цветами после скрыть. и сделать мне это необходимо без code behind. Может как-то можно эту задачку решить в xaml. Может тут конвертер какой нужен. У меня вот решение так и не появилось. Если есть способ, то подскажите, пожалуйста.

Эти две строки всегда будут  в одном и том же месте и меняться не будут. Я пытался привязаться к индексу row, но до конца не реализовал

Comment: А какой ваш тип VM-элемента?

Comment: Как так получилось, что у вас в DataGrid на разных строках выводятся элементы разных типов?

Comment: @VladD У меня привязка к DataTable

Comment: @Андрей , немного не так. У меня просто строки в datatable. Одна как раз та, что мне нужна, а другая строка (тоже формат string) - признак цвета. И в зависимости от значения в этой строке мне необходимо раскрасить соотв. значения ячеек в другой строке.

Comment: Ну преобразуйте DataTable в нормальную коллекцию объектов, зачем мучаться-то?

Comment: а если строки 3? А если сортировка элементов другая? а если а если а если... Очень плохой вариант управлять одним элементом коллекции смотря на другой...

Comment: @Дмитрий Чистик , сортировка отключена. Элементов всегда одно и тоже число. Приходится так делать. Я понимаю, что это не очень правильно, но так необходимо.

Comment: @Андрей, как мне это поможет при такой же структуре?

Comment: Думаю стоит все-таки использовать IValueConverter, без него будет гемор и дохренамилион тегов в XAML

Comment: @Gadman, это поможет вам тем, что с разметкой не будет никаких проблем. Вообще. Она будет проста и лаконична.

Comment: Или делать свой DataViewModel, как предлагает Андрей. Что будет лучшим вариантом решения по-моему.

Comment: @Андрей , хорошо. Но разве это поможет мне решить проблему с раскашиванием?

Comment: @Gadman, иначе я бы вам этого не предлагал.

Comment: @VladD, а можете подсказать в чате: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64607/room-for--and-vladd

Comment: @Gadman написал ответ, если будут какие-либо вопросы по работе с предложенным пакетом или мой ответ не до конца понятен - не стесняйтесь делать мне пинг в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте класс, который будет описывать ячейку:

```
class Cell
{
    public string Value { get; }
    public string Color { get; }

    public Cell(string value, string color)
    {
        Value = value;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

Создайте класс, который будет описывать строку:

```
class Row
{
    public Cell Column1 { get; }
    public Cell Column2 { get; }
    public Cell Column3 { get; }

    public Row(Cell column1, Cell column2, Cell column3)
    {
        Column1 = column1;
        Column2 = column2;
        Column3 = column3;
    }
}
```

Заведите коллекцию строк и запишите в нее данные из DataTable:

```
public List<Row> Table { get; }

Конструктор
{
    var values = dataTable.Rows[0].ItemArray;
    var colors = dataTable.Rows[1].ItemArray;

    Table = new List<Row>();
    Table.Add
    (
        new Row
        (
            new Cell((string)values[0], (string)colors[0]),
            new Cell((string)values[1], (string)colors[1]),
            new Cell((string)values[2], (string)colors[2])
        )
    );
}
```

Разметка DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="заголовок 1"
                            Binding="{Binding Column1.Value}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Column1.Color}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="заголовок 2"
                            Binding="{Binding Column2.Value}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Column2.Color}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="заголовок 3"
                            Binding="{Binding Column3.Value}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Column3.Color}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Результат:

[image: ScreenShot]

---

Решение с привязкой к DataTable (спасибо за помощь @VladD).

Используется класс `Cell` показанный выше, мы преобразуем входную `DataTable` с `string` в `Datatable` с `Cell`:

```
public DataTable Table { get; }

конструктор
{
    ...

    Table = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataColumn column in InputTable.Columns)
        Table.Columns.Add(column);

    for (int i = 0; i < InputTable.Rows.Count / 2; ++i)
    {
        var values = InputTable.Rows[2 * i].ItemArray;
        var colors = InputTable.Rows[2 * i + 1].ItemArray;
        Table.Rows.Add(values.Zip(colors, (v, c) => new Cell((string)v, (string)c)).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Еще потребуется конвертер:

```
public class DataRowViewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DataGridCell cell && cell.DataContext is DataRowView drv)
            return drv.Row[cell.Column.SortMemberPath];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Теперь разметка:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:DataRowViewConverter x:Key="drvc"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource drvc}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Tag.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

и подписчик в CodeBehind:

```
void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var column = (DataGridTextColumn)e.Column;
    column.Binding = new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(FrameworkElement.Tag) + "." + nameof(Cell.Value)),
        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridCell), 1)
    };
    column.SortMemberPath = e.PropertyName;
    column.IsReadOnly = true;
}
```

Немного замудрено, но таков `DataGrid`.

Если вы хотите редактировать значения, то установку `IsReadOnly` нужно убрать, но не забудьте тогда добавить сеттер в `Cell.Value`

Comment: спасибо огромное за пример. Извините, за то что не написал сразу: число столбцов может меняться ( как можно сделать ваш пример более динамичным? Ещё раз прошу прощения, что сразу не уточнил это. Заголовки берутся из datatable columnname

Comment: Вы какой-то функционал DataGrid кроме отображения данных используете? Возможно будет проще отказаться вообще от `DataGrid` пользу `ItemsControl`, например.

Comment: да, использую. Отслеживание изменений в ячейках. Некоторые расчеты в ячейках. Более подходит datagrid. Только вот эта проблема с раскраской...

Comment: В таком случае берите класс `Cell` из этого ответа и из своей `DataTable` формируйте новую `DataTable`, у которой в ячейках будут элементы типа `Cell`

Comment: @Gadman ячейки у вас одного типа?

Comment: @Foggy Finder , да

Comment: @Gadman тогда почему бы просто не привязаться к массиву?

Comment: @Gadman можно узнать, если у вас всего одна строка, то зачем использовать `DataGrid`?

Comment: @Foggy Finder строк штук 5)) я лишь пример привел. Индексы строк не меняются.

Comment: @Gadman я бы на вашем месте просто привязался к массиву

Comment: @Foggy Finder , в каком плане к массиву? Вместо datatable?

Comment: @Gadman к массиву ячеек `Cell` из этого ответа

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64699/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-gadman).

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю воспользоваться специальным пакетом [Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D) чтобы можно было использовать привязку к массивам массивов, с которой работать во многом удобнее чем с `DataTable`.
Для того, чтобы установить пакет с помощью [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D/) можно использовать следующую команду

```
Install-Package Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D
```

Тогда вы сможете установить для ячейки шаблон, в котором и применить привязку данных. Например:

```
    <DataGrid Margin="5"
              dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.RowsSource="{Binding Data}"
              SelectionUnit="Cell">
        <dataGrid2D:Cell.Template>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Background="{Binding Color}" Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </dataGrid2D:Cell.Template>
    </DataGrid>
```

(предполагаю, что вы используете класс `Cell` из другого ответа для описания ячейки).

Пример отображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно видеть каждая ячейка может быть закрашена в свой цвет

Вы можете задать заголовки для строк и столбцов следующим образом:

```
dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.ColumnHeadersSource="{Binding ColumnHeaders}"
dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.RowHeadersSource="{Binding RowHeaders}"
```

Перед использованием важно не забывать добавить объявление:

```
xmlns:dataGrid2D="http://gu.se/DataGrid2D"
```

или (если у вас F# проект и вы работает через FsXAML)

```
xmlns:dataGrid2D="clr-namespace:Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D;assembly=Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D"
```